# ClassNotFoundException Sandwich.Java... where is it?

Tags: java, class, enums, import, package

Ok so I have a file called 'Sandwich.java' at the root folder and a file called 'SandwichType.java' inside of a folder at [root]/MyFrstPkg. For whatever reason it won't compile claiming that Sandwich.java cannot be found. Here is the directory structure:

```
root --
      |
      |- Sandwich.java
      |
      |-MyFirstPkg
                 |
                 |-SandwichType.java
```

Here is Sandwich.java:

```
//note I also tried adding package MyFrstPkg; in this file as well and removing the leading MyFrstPkg. from the import statement below, still no luck.

import MyFrstPkg.SandwichType; //the text 'MyFrstPkg' part is underlined as an error

class Sandwich{

   SandwichType type;   //the text 'SandwichType' is underlined as an error

   public static void main(String[] args){

      Sandwich sndwch1 = new Sandwich();

      sndwch1.type = SandwichType.HAM; //the text 'SandwichType' is underlined as an error

      System.out.println("A HAM costs $"+sndwch1.type.getCost());
      System.out.println("and has "+ sndwch1.type.getSlices()+" slices.");
   }

}
```

and here is SandwichType.java:

```
package MyFrstPkg;

enum SandwichType{

   HAM(0,0f);

   SandwichType(int numSlices, float cost){ // constructor - Ryan changed 'numslices' to 'numSlices'
      this.numSlices = numSlices;
      this.cost      = cost;  
   } //end constructor 

   private int numSlices; //These are specific to this 
   private float cost;    // enum class...

   public int getSlices(){
      return numSlices;
   }

   public float getCost(){
      return cost;
   }

}//end of SandwichType enum
```

I browse in CMD to the root location and run 'java Sandwich.java' and all I get is a ClassNotFoundExeption Sandwich.Java, why is it not found? IT IS ITSELF D:

Answer (score 1):

To compile your class, use

```
javac Sandwich.java
```

If this gives no error messages, you should be able to call

```
java Sandwich
```

to start your program.

---

If the first works without error, we are one step further. If the second does not work, try this instead:

```
java -cp . Sandwich
```

If it works this way, you have set some wrong classpath. Type `echo %CLASSPATH%` and post the result. (Normally you should not need the CLASSPATH variable at all for simple projects.)

Comment: sigh, javac is not a recognized command even though I just mapped the system variable :( ... OK I had the wrong PATH set, it's working now, but I am getting the error listed above when I try to run the class now that it is compiled...

Comment: Please be clear and say precisely which error you have. And how are you running the class?

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans is very project-based, so I'd try creating a basic `Java Application` project and putting them in there.

Comment: Ok I've taken this out of NetBeans all together and now I am just using Notepad++ and trying to compile with java in the CMD, I keep getting Class Not Found error on Sandwich.Java now, I'm so confused.

Answer (score 0):

The name of your project becomes the base package name if you choose "new project" then "java application". You would want to choose "java project with existing sources" if you already have the package/directory structure set up.

If you choose "java application" you can delete the default package name, then right click on the project name, choose "New" Then "Java Package ..." from the list.

**EDIT:** - Sorry... didn't notice. Your classes aren't public. That's your real problem.

```
public class Sandwich { ...
public enum SandwichType { ...
```

As for trying to run `java Sandwich.java` ... er, you can't. That's source code. It has to be compiled to a class first.

Comment: I've taken out NetBeans from the equation entirely, now I am simply getting a class not found error when trying to compile on the command line, see updates above.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't really looking at your code. Try making your classes `public` ... otherwise they can't be accessed across packages.

Comment: Made the class and the enum both public, compile seems to return no errors, in fact it returns nothing, but the Sandwich.class file does exist now. When I run it with 'java' it throws the same error that I have listed above class not found exception for Sandwich.

Comment: How are you trying to run it? Should be 'java Sandwich' while you are in the same directory as the `Sandwich.class` file